# Is there an adjective that means "does not emit CO2 or cause pollution"?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's an adjective for it. I know people use the word "green", but "green" doesn't necessarily mean that it doesn't emit CO2 or cause pollution.

For example:

> The green electric car burned and crashed down the road, but the green flying saucer flew by.

Comment: Try *inert* or *harmless*, or *eco-friendly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would carbon neutral do it?

It might.

Answer (score 1):

"Environmentally Friendly" is a phrase that might be used. Certainly it could be applied to whatever the speaker considered free of harmful environmental effects.